# SSO with Django and Active Directory

Tags: django, active-directory

I have a web application developed using Django. It's hosted remotely on AWS but deployed to clients using their local networks.

At the moment users just sign in using the standard django authentication approach. They each have their own usernames, passwords specific to the app, etc.

I would like to be able to provide single sign on, so users who are already authenticated by active directory will be logged directly to the site.

Is this possible with an app hosted on AWS? I assume there would have to be some kind of hook into AD?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895377/single-sign-on-to-django-site-via-remote-active-directory) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142717/get-client-active-directory-username-from-django) answer, but they appear to work for intranet apps only.